# How to response "How are you doing"

Tags: greetings

I've been in the US for a while and been greeted by others `how're you doing` frequently. I always respond `I'm fine` or `I'm great` if he/she is a stranger or normal friend. But it's kind of embarrassing to close friends in the same way and might cause a cold situation. I'm wondering how do you guys respond to that and transform a chit-chat into a deeper discussion. Any insight and thought can be helpful.

Comment: You have to be careful how much detail you go into even with close friends. I once had someone described to me as "He's alright but when you ask him how he is, he tells you". The question "How're you  doing?" is a formalised greeting, not usually a request for information. This seems to be true of other cultures as well, the normal response to "Ni hao" (Are you well?) In Chinese is "Hen hao, xiexie" (very well thank you).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because answers will be at least largely informed by opinion: far from ideal on ELU. I suggest that InterpersonalSkills.SE is the logical place to ask.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm good/I'm great/I'm fine are acceptable in all situations, the easiest way to make it a deeper discussion is simply to ask "How are you?" and continue the discussion by asking another question/ if they have a question. answer theirs, and you can easily continue that discussion

Answer (score -1):

No citation, but it depends on the subculture entirely. You might just nod your head a little for general Americans of either gender. For a close friend, you might punch them in the upper arm medial muscle with your fist you are a typical white person who retains those traditions,A0864nd if a female is in-group, you punch her in the arm as hard as she can take it. You use your fist as hard as you can, depending on the person. That's why I hate being punched in the arm by most people as I am "tender" which means that act is uncomfortable.

Saying "How're your doing" or any subregional variation on that is a ritualized greeting, and you don't have to say anything to someone or back to someone just to respond or to ask. Totally dependent on the in-group and out-group nature. Witness the "fist-bump" popularized by Obama,9876f

Comment: Oh my geez. "Typical white person?" Just say no to racism.